# Does this imply that I am ineligible to apply for this grant?

Tags: funding, research-proposal

Comment of grant reviewer in the field of chemistry:

> order to be eligible, your study must involve an inferential statistical test, and it appears your study will instead quantify the conditions required to [chemistry term]

Why would a grant in chemistry require such statistical test? Nowhere in the announcement of the grant was this pointed out. Am I understanding chemistry wrong?

Comment: It might help to include more of the quote for context.

Comment: It might also help if you point out what the program is. We can’t guess what the requirements are.

Comment: @aeismail New trends in environmental chemistry- sustainable environmental technology fund

Comment: @Nat I wish I have more, that was reply from reviewer from grant agency

Comment: Any number of stochastic models in chemistry are appropriately analyzed using statistical tests.

Comment: @Fomite but how I can test conditions? in statistical way? it is not wide range, there are no temperature, ph, humidity, etc influences

Comment: I’m not saying *your* project fits, just that it’s conceivable that a chemistry research project might heavily involve stats.

Comment: @Fomite yes, you are right, but why would they ( founding body) think of grant just using that in context of env. technology?  inferential test for new technology. that sound more like applied research rather than basic.

Comment: @SSimon There are pure applications that might use stats as well. Perhaps they just want to specifically target and push projects using stats?

Comment: Maybe, but what would be purpose of it? @Fomite

Comment: @SSimon To promote research using a particular methodology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s hard to say for sure, but at larger granting agencies, different review panels may focus on different areas and have quite stringent guidelines for what is considered on-topic. It may be that you need to have a statistical test as part of the guidelines for the area under which you asked your proposal to be judged. The reviewer’s response may be suggesting your submission falls out of their purview.

Comment: I wonder why they didnt point out in grant call. They just pointed out about expected publishing and outcome of research, if I knew that also methodology predeterminated, I would apply

Comment: It may be posted separately from the grant call itself.

Comment: @aesismall where can I check this?

Comment: You’d have to look at the agency’s website.